# Is my way of proving that y is even correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $F$ be a linear tranformation such that:
$$F(y,x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Assume $F(y(x),-x)=-F(y(x),x)$.

Show that $y(x)=y(-x)$.

Now I first wanted to show that $y'(-x)=-y'(x)$. I showed it this way:

$$ y'(-x) = F(y(-x),-x) = -F(y(-x), x) = -F(y(t),-t) = F(y(t), t) = y'(t) = \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} = y'(x) \cdot (-1) = -y'(x) $$

(where: $t=-x$.)

and from here it's pretty obvious that $y(-x)=y(x)$.

Now, my question is- Is my solution ok? It just seems so simple, I think there might be some small mistake I'm missing.

Thanks!